# throwE and catchE with ExceptT monad on the bottom of monadic stack

Tags: haskell, exception, monads, monad-transformers

Say I have a monadic stack like this:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
import Control.Monad.Trans

type MyMonad = ReaderT Env (ExceptT String IO) -- Env is irrelevant
```

And a function (simplified, but the idea holds):

```
f :: Integer -> MyMonad Integer
f 42 = lift $ throwE "42 is an ILLEGAL number"
f n = return n
```

What I now want to do is call `f` from another function, but catch the thrown exception if it occurs and somehow handle it (for instance, throw another exception but with the message changed). I'm having a hard time figuring out what kind of lift operations should be done here for it to be done properly. I tried something like this:

```
g n = do
  x <- (f n) `catchE'` (\_ -> lift $ throwE "nope, still illegal")
  return x
where catchE' - lift . catchE
```

but it obviously won't work because `catchE'` takes something in the `ExceptT` monad, not `MyMonad`. Can it be done easily? Perhaps changing the structure of the monad stack could help?

Answer (score 5):

You need more than `lift` to lift `catch` through a monad transformer. In fact, there are transformers with no way to lift `catch` at all (such as `ContT`). However for `ReaderT` there is, and the easiest way to make use of that is via `Control.Monad.Error.catchError` from the mtl library.

Comment: So something like: `f n \`catchError\` throwError "NOPE"`? It doesn't work

Comment: Okay, I see. `f n \`catchError\` (\_ -> throwError "NOPE")` works as intended. Thank you!